# Multiples foreign key for 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I have this problem:

I have a "school" database and need to reference  the Teachers table with the Subject table.

Teachers will instruct more than one subject. And here is the problem.

***Teachers table:***

- id_Teacher **<- PK**
- id_Subject
- id_Course
- name
- surname
- address

etc.

***Subject table:***

- id_Subject **<- PK**
- name

I always worked with 1 value on foreign key. ex:

```
SELECT * FROM Teachers WHERE id_Subject = 1
```

but now I don't really know what I have to do.

Comment: A teacher can have many subjects.  Can a subject have many teachers?

Comment: First you need one more table for the relation  "teacher instructs subject" Kind of Instructs(teacher_id , subject_id)

Comment: You can try the IN clause ...  select * from teachers where id_subject in (select id_subject from SubjectTable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you're trying to describe is called a "many to many" relationship.  It requires an intermediary table to connect the entity tables, and in many cases the intermediary table becomes a business entity in and of itself.

Consider for example:

```
Teachers
----------
ID
Name
etc.

Subjects
----------
ID
Name
etc.

TeacherSubjects
----------
ID
TeacherID (FK to Teachers)
SubjectID (FK to Subjects)
```

The relationship between the `Teachers` and the `Subjects` itself becomes a place to potentially store data.  Thinking about the subject domain (a school), the `TeacherSubjects` table sounds like it might be a `Classes` table waiting to happen.  Where you could put information about a given instance of a class, which is a business entity that has a teacher and a subject.

Answer (score 0):

You say "Teachers will instruct more than one subject."  From this I understand that a teacher may instruct multiple subjects. Then, it is wrong for a teacher to have an `id_Subject`, because that would mean that a teacher can only teach one subject.

If you make the subject contain an `id_Teacher`, then each subject will refer to a teacher, and therefore it will be possible to make multiple subjects have the same teacher.  Which is the same as saying that a single teacher will teach multiple subjects.

If, on the other hand, you need to have not only one teacher teaching multiple subjects, but also a subject being taught by multiple teachers, (many-to-many relationship,) then clearly, you cannot put `id_Teacher` in subject, because this forces a single subject to be taught by only one teacher.  In that case neither your teacher row can have an id_Subject, nor your subject row can have an id_Teacher.  Instead, you will need an extra table, say "TeachersSubjects", where each row will have an `id_Subject` and an `id_Teacher`, essentially listing all the possible combinations of teachers and subjects.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is relation many-to-many, teacher can has multiple subjects, and subject can have multiple teachers, you need additional table.